# New Communication site Template supports Multilingual Content

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-custom-property-pane

we have a requirement to use new Communication Site template and build a web site, but it should be multilingual.

Since new Communication site look and feel and responsiveness suit to my client requirement and client insisted to use this template.

Now i have challenge how to render the Content in multilingual.

Example :
In Hero Tile webpart i want to have Title of each tile will be shown different based on User language. as shown in picture
[image]

Please help me if its possible.I have worked previously in SPFX webpart with multilingual but i don't want to develop completely new as client want to leverage existing functionality.

Note : Please provide the response around the OOTB SPFx webpart  Multilingual capability, like Hero Webpart not Multilingual Page capability

Answer (score 2):

Vinit,

There isn't anything available out of the box *yet*, but there is a "patterns and practices" (PnP) solution that you can find at:

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-solutions/tree/master/solutions/MultilingualPages

It allows you to create multi-language page equivalents, and automatically redirect users to a page that matches their language.

I hope this helps?

Comment: Anything custom I can develop. I wanted to know if Microsoft comes with a strategy to provide multilingual in their ootb spfx webpart. Like hero same webpart has a configuration like language, and admin configure two different title for two different language user. And based on user language, hero title displays. This already I have done with custom spfx wanted to know if ootb will have in future. Since not every time business agree for customization

Comment: It's unlikely there will be anything out of the box in the near future. The SPFx solution above is the current official way to implement multi-lingual in modern sites.

Comment: If you are considering developing your own, I would highly recommend you give the PnP solution posted here first.  Even though it is not an "official" Microsoft solution, PnP code is written primarily by Microsoft employees and MVP's.

Answer (score 0):

Multilingual Page Publishing can be found on the [roadmap](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=50217), scheduled for release in March.

In various blogs and available sessions, [like this one from Ignite](https://myignite.techcommunity.microsoft.com/sessions/81506?source=sessions), you can see how this will be implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. Please provide the response around the OOTB SPFx webpart Multilingual capability, like Hero Webpart not Multilingual Page capability if available

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking about. The web part properties, like the titles in the Hero web part, are embedded on the page itself. Thus - if you have separate pages for different languages - you should be able to translate these as well just like any other content on the page.
For the web parts, there is localization support, but this will vary from web part to web part: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/localize-web-parts but I don't think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: You are right, Page customisation might suit, if we create 16 different Home page  and add multiple OOTB webparts. I want to if any Translation capability of  Hero webpart Title, so we can provide multiple  title Translation in a same webpart and it displayed based on user Language. we have done the same capability for Custom Webparts, was requesting if it can come OOTB in future.